# Is it possible to add extra functionality to compiled, close-source applications ie. Microsoft Word?

Tags: python, user-interface, architecture, software-design

For a while now, I have been wondering how I can add extra functionality to applications (MacOS) by writing scripts in Python without having access to its' source code. I have come across solutions like code injection but could find a more simple way of doing it. Ie. a python library that already exists?

**What do I mean by extra functionality?**

If I have an extra menu bar item (for example) that doesn't interact directly with the application itself but can run another python script as part of that application. Ie, if you click on a menu bar item another GUI would pop up. An example use case would be in Microsoft Word where I have an extra menu bar item where I can search for English-related questions on the English SO.

**Menu Bar Clarification** :

[image]

Please excuse me if my question is unrealistic or lacks any understanding of how this would be even possible, however, I thought there's nowhere better to ask a question than StackOverflow.

**EDIT**
Although I use Microsoft Word as an example, I would like to be able to do this on any application that runs on MacOS.

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/word Have fun!

Comment: Hi, I don't want to do this just for Microsoft Word as this was an example, any ideas on how to do it on any application?

Comment: That's not possible. The application has to provide an interface for that. Most don't.

Comment: Oh right, not even via code injection?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to add functionality to an application that doesn't expose an interface designed for extensibility.

The isolation between applications is enforced at the Operating System level, because each application has its own process which has its own private address space that cannot be accessed by other processes.